# replace string between two delimiters shell in a certain position in shell

Tags: bash, shell

How do I replace a string between two delimiters?

In a line wherestrings are separated by ";" ,I'd like to replace the string in the 3rd position by another string($new_value)
The string in the 3rd position can appear multiple times in the same line but it should only be changed in the 3rd position

I've tried

```
echo $laligne | awk -v repl=${new_value} -F ";" '{ printf("%s;%s;%s;%s;%s",$1,$2,repl,$4,$5)}' >> file.txt
```

and

```
old_value=`echo $line | awk '{split($0,a,";");print a[3]}'`
echo $laligne | awk -F ";"  '{gsub($old_value,$new_value,$3)}1' OFS=";" >> file.txt
```

when checking the file content ,I find the line unchanged

Can you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements are separated by ";" so regexp "**[^;]+**" will give them to us and we need **3**rd :

```
$ echo "1  ;2    ;3   ;4   ;5   ;6   " | sed "s/[^;]\+/replace/3"
1  ;2    ;replace;4   ;5   ;6
```

Comment: my input can have spaces in the string ie :   echo "sub-string1 sub-string2 sub-string3;2;3;;5;6" | sed "s/[^;]/replace/3"
Output : sureplace-string1 sub-string2 sub-string3;2;3;;5;6

Comment: updated to your case

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- want to change field #3 in **all** lines (assuming this code may be applied against a `;`-delimited file that contains multiple lines)
- do not know how many fields may exist in a line

Keeping with an `awk` solution whereby we simply replace field #3 (`$3`) with the new value:

```
$ laligne='a;b;c;d;e;f'
$ awk -v repl='new_value' 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} {$3=repl; print}' <<< "${laligne}"
a;b;new_value;d;e;f
```